# SharePoint error: "File Not Found"

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web project that lives within SharePoint 2007. A couple of days ago, I made two changes to several pages, the first change was to adding a script reference to a jQuery file inside of my script folder that I lives with in my web project.

The second change was where I replace all of my DatePicker controls from SharePoint's DateTime control and I had to add a `<% Register....SharePoint.WebControls` reference at the top of this one page.

After I have compiled the solution in release mode and deployed out to my production environment, I started to get a "File Not Found" error when I try to access the page from SharePoint. I have no idea what's going on. We have recycle the app pool and even the stack trace doesn't tell use that much. Below is a view of the stack trace that I received when accessing the page. Please help, I've been looking at this issue for days now.

```
File Not Found.   at System.Signature._GetSignature(SignatureStruct& signature, Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, IntPtr fieldHandle, IntPtr methodHandle, IntPtr declaringTypeHandle) 
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(SignatureStruct& signature, Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandle fieldHandle, RuntimeMethodHandle methodHandle, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringTypeHandle) 
   at System.Signature..ctor(RuntimeFieldHandle fieldHandle, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringTypeHandle) 
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.get_FieldType() 
   at System.Web.UI.Util.GetNonPrivateFieldType(Type classType, String fieldName) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildFieldDeclaration(ControlBuilder builder) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTreeFromBuilder(ControlBuilder builder, Boolean fInTemplate, Boolean topLevelControlInTemplate, PropertyEntry pse) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTreeFromBuilder(ControlBuilder builder, Boolean fInTemplate, Boolean topLevelControlInTemplate, PropertyEntry pse) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTreeFromBuilder(ControlBuilder builder, Boolean fInTemplate, Boolean topLevelControlInTemplate, PropertyEntry pse) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.TemplateControlCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildMiscClassMembers() 
   at System.Web.Compilation.PageCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildMiscClassMembers() 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTree() 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.GenerateCode(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder) 
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.AddBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a familiar one. It's related to the version of System.Web.Extensions that's requested by the SharePoint DateTime control. It seems that it is using Ajax and you aren't referencing the right Ajax platform version.

Steps similar to the ones described here solved my problem:
http://paulsiu.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/file-not-found-error-when-you-select-new-webpart-after-installing-smartpart-13/

Comment: I've also added some new fields to a list that my custom aspx page uses to display? Would that cause this error? And I'm not using a WebPart, but I'm using a custom aspx page. So you think the real problem is the date time control.

Comment: On my production server I have version 1.0.61 of System.Web.Extensions, but on my development server I have 3.5.0.0. And it works on my dev box. Is it the System.Web.Extensions version from old?